# Scala function return type based on generic

Tags: scala, generics, playframework, playframework-2.0

Using Scala generics I'm trying to abstract some common functions in my Play application. The functions return `Seq`s with objects deserialized from a REST JSON service.

```
def getPeople(cityName: String): Future[Seq[People]] = {
    getByEndpoint[People](s"http://localhost/person/$cityName")
}

def getPeople(): Future[Seq[Dog]] = {
    getByEndpoint[Dog]("http://localhost/doge")
}
```

The fetch and deserialization logic is packed into a single function using generics.

```
private def getByEndpoint[T](endpoint: String): Future[Seq[T]] = {

    ws.url(endpoint)
      .get()
      .map(rsp => rsp.json)
      .flatMap { json =>
        json.validate[Seq[T]] match {
          case s: JsSuccess[Seq[T]] =>
            Future.successful(s.get)
          case e: JsError =>
            Future.failed(new RuntimeException(s"Get by endpoint JSON match failed: $e"))
        }
      }

}
```

Problem is is I'm getting "`No Json deserializer found for type Seq[T]. Try to implement an implicit Reads or Format for this type.`". I'm sure I'm not using `T` properly in `Seq[T]` (according to my C#/Java memories at least), but I can't find any clue how to do it the proper way in Scala. Everything works as expected without using generics.

Comment: Try changing `def getByEndpoint[T]` to `def getByEndpoint[T: Format]`? If that works for you I'd be happy to write up an answer explaining why.

Comment: It does! My guess is that it has something to do with the `Json.format`s I have set on the models. Can you please post a reply so I can mark it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Play JSON uses [type classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class) to capture information about which types can be (de-)serialized to and from JSON, and how. If you have an implicit value of type `Format[Foo]` in scope, that's referred to as an instance of the `Format` type class for `Foo`.

The advantage of this approach is that it gives us a way to constrain generic types (and have those constraints checked at compile time) that doesn't depend on subtyping. For example, there's no way the standard library's `String` will ever extend some kind of `Jsonable` trait that Play (or any other library) might provide, so we need some way of saying "we know how to encode `String`s as JSON" that doesn't involve making `String` a subtype of some trait we've defined ourselves.

In Play JSON you can do this by defining implicit `Format` instances, and Play itself provides many of these for you (e.g., if you've got one for `T`, it'll give you one for `Seq[T]`). The `validate` method on `JsValue` requires one of these instances (actually a subtype of `Format`, `Reads`, but that's not terribly relevant here) for its type parameter—`Seq[T]` in this case—and it won't compile unless the compiler can find that instance.

You can provide this instance by adding the constraint to your own generic method:

```
private def getByEndpoint[T: Format](endpoint: String): Future[Seq[T]] = {
  ...
}
```

Now with the `T: Format` syntax you've specified that there has to be a `Format` instance for `T` (even though you don't constraint `T` in any other way), so the compiler knows how to provide the `Format` instance for `Seq[T]` that the `json.validate[Seq[T]]` call requires.